# How to serializing a generic TList to JSON using mormot

Tags: delphi, mormot

I want to serialize a generic `TList` to JSON using the mORMot framework.

I know there is a `TDynList` which has a convenient method called `SaveToJSON`, but it not suit for me.

This is my simple demo:

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Generics.Collections, SynCommons, SynDB, SynDBODBC, mORMot, mORMotSQLite3;

const
  CONN_STR =
    'Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.3 UNICODE Driver;Database=test;Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;UID=root;Pwd=';

type
  TRows = TList<Variant>;

  TDbService = class
    constructor Create(const ConnStr: RawUTF8); overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  protected
    fConnStr: RawUTF8;
    fProps: TODBCConnectionProperties;
    function GetConnection: TODBCConnectionProperties;
    function Query(const Sql: RawUTF8; const Params: array of const): TRows;
  public
    function GetSpecificUserList(Offset, Limit: Integer): TRows;
  end;

{ TDbService }

constructor TDbService.Create(const ConnStr: RawUTF8);
begin
  fConnStr := ConnStr;
end;

destructor TDbService.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

function TDbService.GetConnection: TODBCConnectionProperties;
begin
  Result := TODBCConnectionProperties.Create('', fConnStr, '', '');
end;

function TDbService.Query(const Sql: RawUTF8; const Params: array of const): TRows;
var
  Props: TODBCConnectionProperties;
  Row: ISQLDBRows;
  V: Variant;
begin
  Props := GetConnection;
  Result := TRows.Create;
  try
    try
      Row := Props.Execute(Sql, Params);
      while Row.Step do
      begin
        Row.RowDocVariant(V);
        Result.Add(Row);
      end;
    except
      FreeAndNil(Result);
      raise
    end;
  finally
    Props.Free;
  end;
end;

function TDbService.GetSpecificUserList(Offset, Limit: Integer): TRows;
begin
  // It calls a stored procedure, the Result will be a TList<Variant> .
  // Each Variant has properties like name, age, etc. as it's an User representation but not from any existed table) .
  Result := Query('CALL GetSpecUserList_P(?, ?)', [Offset, Limit]);
end;


{ Main }

procedure Main;
var
  DbService: TDbService;
  Rows: TList<Variant>;
begin
  DbService := TDbService.Create(CONN_STR);
  try
    Rows := DbService.GetSpecificUserList(0, 100);
    // How to serialize `Rows` to a JSON string? I'm not using TDynList because it could only hold of records, but not Variant.
  finally
    DbService.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  Main;
end.
```

How to convert `Rows` to a JSON string? I'm not using TDynList because it could only hold of records, but not Variant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please mention reason for down vote , It will help me to improve my question next time. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I wrote a tool-function like this:

```
function VariantListToJson(const List: TList<Variant>): RawUTF8;
var
  Item: Variant;
  S: RawUTF8;
begin
  Result := '[';
  for Item in List do
  begin
    S := VariantSaveJSON(Item);
    Result := Result + S + ',';
  end;
  if Result <> '[' then
    Delete(Result, Length(Result), 1);
  Result := Result + ']';
end;
```